# Move local uncommitted changes to new branch

Tags: git

I have uncommitted local changes. I would like to create a new branch and move the changes there.

Is my understanding correct? I should do:

```
git diff > my_work.txt
git checkout -b new_branch_name
git push origin new_branch_name
git apply my_work.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `git stash`:

## Stash your changes (included untracked files)

```
git stash push --include-untracked
```

## Verify clean working directory with git status

```
git status
```

## Checkout your branch

```
git checkout <MyFancyBranch>
```

## Apply stashed changes to current branch

```
git stash pop
```

Answer (score 0):

`git stash` makes this a little easier.

```
$ git stash
$ git stash branch new_branch_name
```

This will preserved both staged *and* unstaged changes before creating and checking out the new branch.